# Simple .htaccess won't rewrite and seems not to match at all

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

It should be straight forward. http://example.com/denver-cars/ does not redirect to http://example.com/newcars-in-denver/. It simply tries to load /denver-cars/ and denver-cars is in the URL. Am I missing something here? I have tried moving it up and down the list of rules and have tried numerous types of flags to no avail. Anyone shed light on my 3 hr problem that takes 10sec to fix?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# Redirect google index dir's to new dir
RewriteRule ^/(.*)-cars/ /newcars-in-$1/  [NC,R=301,L]

# Disable rewrite for Folder Names
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^awstats
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Permit pretty URL directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [L]

## Allow image hotlinks from my domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example\.com?.*$
RewriteRule .*\.jpg$      -        [F,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a leading slash in your regex. URLs that are used to match rules that are in an htaccess file has the leading slash removed so `^/(.*)` will never match anything. You want:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-cars/ /newcars-in-$1/  [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. You're right but that does not resolve the problem. I updated it and it is still behaving the same way. (I have cleared my cache and even changed URLS but the behaivor is still the same)